# How to make objects in an array go through a function

Tags: c#, arrays

I have this object array called `blocks`, and i want each object in the array go through a function.

This is the code that i have...

```
object[] blocks = new object[2];
blocks[0] = block;
blocks[1] = block1;
blocks[2] = block2;

if (player.Bottom >= screen.Bottom)
{
    jump = false;
    jumped = false;
}
else if (player.Right >= i.Left + 5 &&
    player.Left <= i.Right - 5 &&
    player.Bottom >= i.Top &&
    player.Bottom <= i.Bottom - 10)
{
    force = 0;
    jump = false;
    player.Top = i.Location.Y - player.Height;
}
else
{
    player.Top += 5;
    jumped = false;
    nothing = false;
}
```

i would like to know on how to replace the `i` with every object in the array `blocks`. So that it will do the function with every single block. Instead of having to make a separate function for every single block ( there will be over 50 objects in original code, this is just a simplified version of it).

Comment: There's an entire manual on the C# Programming Language. You should look at it before asking basic questions on the syntax of the language. See [C# Programming Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67ef8sbd.aspx) . For detailed reference, see the [C# Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/618ayhy6.aspx).

Comment: Have fun with that line: blocks[2] = block2;

Comment: rbaghbanli means that since you declared the array of size 2, and the array indexes are zero-based, you should not attempt to access the element with index 2, since this is the (non-existent) *third* element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple `foreach` statement should suffice:

```
foreach (block b in blocks) 
{
    YourFunction(b);
}
```

EDIT: MSDN Documentation has more info and should help you if you get stuck: "[Using foreach with Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2h3zzhdw.aspx)".

Comment: I have a problem, whenever it executes the code, it says "NullReferenceException". Any help?

Comment: The full stack trace should show you which line/assignment/function etc is causing the error

Comment: It says that blocks is null, even though i assigned it block1 and 1.